# android tablerow and columns in code

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

I'm trying to create a `TableLayout` with dynamically added rows and columns (from an array of obbjects). Since it's dynamic must I code(?)

All the examples I can find is doing it using xml layouts. The only ones out there that does it in code only adds a single view, like a button, which makes me believe its not doable, and I need two columns at least, where one of the will contain a view with an image and text.

Answer (score 3):

Try to create table and row doing something like this

```
TableLayout t=new TableLayout(this);
TableRow tr=new TableRow(this);
```

and add row with table by

```
t.addView(tr);
```

similarly you can add other view (text, image view etc.) by using `addView()` function

Comment: Thanks, i did that but since i don't have columns in my row they all get stacked upon eachother. Im reading about the ListView now, perhaps that's easier

Comment: you can add view to table (without row) by using t.addView(view);